# How to Use COUNT(*), but break down by repeating values in another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL that is formatted like so:

```
ReportLogID | SiteID | ReportName | ReportPath   | UserName | RunDateTime 
------------|--------|------------|--------------|----------|------------
1           | 3      | Report 1   | C:\1.report  |User      | 2014-11-26
2           | 8      | Report 1   | C:\1.report  |User      | 2014-12-20
3           | 3      | Report 2   | C:\2.report  |User      | 2014-12-21
4           | 3      | Report 1   | C:\1.report  |User      | 2014-12-22
```

I have the following code to count the number of times a report has been run total, along with the last date it was run:

```
SELECT ReportName, MAX(RunDateTime) AS LASTRAN, COUNT(*) AS TIMESRAN FROM ReportLog GROUP BY ReportName ORDER BY TIMESRAN DESC
```

I'm needing to run this report taking the SiteID into consideration. I know the report has been run a total of X times, and the last date it was run. However, I need to break it down by SiteID - so Report 1 was run a total of X times for SiteID 3, and last ran on YYYY-MM-DD. I've run into a roadblock.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to consider the SiteID while group

Comment: Is it Monday? I need more coffee... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as following:

```
SELECT ReportName
  , MAX(RunDateTime) AS LASTRAN
  , COUNT(*) AS TIMESRAN
FROM ReportLog
GROUP BY ReportName
  , SiteID
ORDER BY TIMESRAN DESC
```

Comment: Yes, you can display with SiteID by adding it to SELECT too.